# Text won't display in Bootstrap Jumbotron w/ image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a background image to the twitter bootstrap jumbotron class.

I am using Bootstrap3.

I tried this but it alpha'd all the text as well and did not restrict the image to the jumbotron:

```
      .jumbotron:after {
          background: url("img/island.png") repeat scroll center center transparent;
          bottom: 0;
          content: "";
          display: block;
          left: 0;
          opacity: 0.4;
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
      }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This got me 90% of the way but now the text does not show:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style type="text/css">

      .jumbotron {
          position: relative;
          z-index: 3;
      }

      .jumbotron:after {
          background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1)), url('img/carousel_island.png');
          bottom: 0;
          content: "";
          display: block;
          left: 0;
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
          z-index: 2;
      }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should relatively position the `.jumbotron` class so that the pseudo-element is relative to it; If there is no ancestor element that is positioned relatively, absolutely positioned elements is relative to the viewport.

Try adding:

```
.jumbotron {
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That got rid of the positioning issues! Any ideas for the alpha on the text?

Comment: Thanks again. I made those changes but they cause the image to disappear. I posted above the complete css in case I made a mistake. A work around would be just to alpha out the image in an editor. Yet I am green enough to want to understand the issues here.

Comment: I messed the syntax up a bit, this should work now: `background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1)), url('img/island.png');` - I apologize for that. Note that the default direction is to bottom, you can change that value along with the alpha values to suit your needs.

Comment: Awesome. That comes out great. Last problem: No visible text. Not sure why that has disappeared. Tried changing color. The foreground should not have changed......

Comment: Thanks again. I was glad to see css has a z-index, but this made no change. Still just the image. I will post the HTML for the Jumbotron too.

Comment: I added back to the question your version of the classes for clarity.